# Asynchronously send / receive fixed amount of data using tcp socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

In my application I do some asynchronous communication over a TCP socket.

I don't like the fact that the send and receive operations (sync or async) of the Socket class are allowed to finish before the requested number of bytes were transmitted. For example: when I want to read X bytes from the socket, I don't want to care about how many read operations are effectively needed to achieve this (in my application logic). I just want to be notified when it's finished (or when an error occured).

It would be nice to have something like BeginSendFixed, EndSendFixed, BeginReceiveFixed and EndReceiveFixed. Those would behave exactly like BeginSend, EndSend, BeginReceive, EndReceive, but not call the callback before the requested number of bytes was transmitted.

I'm thinking about implementing this by myself, based on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx

In the DoTaskHelper function I would call as many (synchronous) Send or Receive until all data is transmitted.

Is this the way to go or is there a different (better) way to hide the need for multiple sends / receives from my application logic?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `TaskCompletionSource` class for this. This has the advantage of not burning a thread just waiting for I/O. It would probably be easier to wrap the existing (asynchronous) APIs as `Task`s first, and then create your API using `TaskCompletionSource`.

Note that `TaskCompletionSource` was added in .NET 4. If you're not on that platform yet, then I recommend marshaling the completion routines to a UI thread (which can be easily done using the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern socket wrappers in [Nito.Async.Sockets](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/)), and then putting them through a parser that is specific to your protocol (an example of which is [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm restricted to use .NET 2; and I'm not sure whether I want to use a third party library for networking. But anyway, I will have a closer look at your suggestions.

Comment: .NET *2*??? Even Nito.Async requires 3.5 Client... I'd point out to your authorities that you're being forced to use technology more than 5 years old, which is a very long time in Internet time.

Comment: P.S. Do consider a third-party library for networking. It makes it so much easier (there's a lot of corner cases, and a lot of the MSDN sample socket code is simply wrong with respect to those cases). There are several commercial libraries available other than mine.